# Overriding validation for WTForms upon append_entry and pop_entry

Tags: forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Apparently, all my fields need to have `DataRequired()` validators that is why I cant `append_entry()` and `pop_entry()` without filling them all out at first. Is there a way to override (or ignore) the validation when the user just needs to `append_entry()` or `pop_entry()` a field?

I saw these `pre_validate()` and `post_validate()` methods in the [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.Field.pre_validate) but I am having a hard time trying to understand what it does. I would appreciate if somebody would give a clear example. The document itself is also hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Optional()` validator of `Wtforms`:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, StringField
from wtforms.validators import Optional

class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Name", validators=[Optional()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

Comment: All the fields are needed to be required, unfortunately.